# IIS does not allow netsh port forwarding for 80 and 443 ports

Tags: iis, netsh

I have a problem for port forwarding (80,443) via netsh which conflicts with IIS on my windows server 2012

Port forwarding is configured via netsh interface portproxy from external ip:80 to localip:80 (centos on Hyper-V)

for example:
89.211.89.23   80 => 192.168.1.12 80 (does not work, iis not found message)
89.211.89.23   81 => 192.168.1.12 80 (works fine)

It seems IIS listens to 80 port for any ip and blocks traffic

I used netsh http add iplisten command to specify exact ip addresses for iis,
now iis doesn't listen to this ip (no any messages from iis) but port forwarding still does not work for 80 port and works fine for 81

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: "It seems IIS listens to 80 port for any ip and blocks traffic", yes. And 1) why do you still use an end of life Windows release? 2) Why do you need IIS on the hypervisor and then attempt to forward port 80/443 to that CentOS machine? People usually configure that IIS outside as a reverse proxy instead. 3) Server administration/networking configuration is usually off topic here. More of a Server Fault question.

Comment: When you run this command `netsh http show iplisten`, do you get the specified ip? Please check the port occupancy to ensure that no other applications are occupying ports 80 and 443. You can use the commands `netstat -ano | findstr :80` and `netstat -ano | findstr :443` to check.

Comment: Is your problem solved? Any progress on this issue? Make sure your firewall is configured to allow traffic on port 80. You can temporarily disable the firewall for testing purposes or create a rule to allow traffic on port 80.

Comment: @YurongDai Not solved. netsh http show iplisten returns ip addresses used by IIS itself. If I add ip address to iplisten, iis listens to this ip and returns "not found error"

Comment: Have you checked the port occupancy?